# How to find tagged files/folders using the command line in Terminal?

Tags: macos, finder, command-line, finder-tag

What commands do we have for finding tagged files/folders using `find` on the command line?

I have done a search and looked on this site and found nothing.

Comment: Yes - "tag" is one of those words that doesn't yield particularly relevant search results! You should put your [GitHub find](https://github.com/jdberry/tag) in an answer - more people will see it.

Comment: @anki I already marked this as answered and the answer contains exactly what you liked to.

Comment: sorry the duplicate comment text is worded like that. It's just bookkeeping. I was merging similar questions like https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/435931/extract-finder-tags-for-multiple-files?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct command to perform Spotlight searches on the macOS Terminal command line is mdfind.

```
mdfind "kMDItemUserTags == '<your_tags_here>'"
```

The list all the kMD codes:

```
mdimport -A
```

Comment: I marked your answer as accepted. There is a [package](https://github.com/jdberry/tag) on GitHub that also works.

Comment: Nice find, very interesting.

Answer (score 4):

Turns out you can do something as simple as:

```
mdfind 'tag:Blue'
```

Although this will only work in English locales

See this excellent answer that happens to discuss tags: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30281424/404459